# Best place to ask about Facebook history (if any)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I feel like I remember that Facebook used to be private and invitation only but can't find any information to back this up. My efforts finding an answer through Google have mostly returned pages related to Facebook events, since those involve invitations. Likewise, Wikipedia only mentions that the high-school Facebook use to be invitation only (but maybe that's what I'm remembering). Is there a good Stack Exchange site to ask about this, or is it too off topic for any of the existing sites?

Comment: I don't remember it being private but I do remember it requiring a .edu email address in order to create an account... are you certain that's not what you're thinking?

Comment: You talk about the starting idea, do you ? Wikipedia answer you if so; *The founders had initially limited the website's membership to Harvard students, but later expanded...*

Comment: In 20 years or so, you might be able to ask at Retro-computing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook is *generally* on-topic at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). Note that it's a site for questions about *using* web applications. A question asking about the history of Facebook is more than likely just going to get answers that parrot what's at Wikipedia and other public sources.